# Проверка версии обновления и скачивание файлов по FTP C#

Tags: c#, wpf, сеть, ftp

Алгоритм действий:

1. Проверить версию файлов на FTP и сверить версию файлов на локальной машине пользователя. (Возможно путём XML или Hash)
2. Если версия на FTP новее, чем на локальной машине пользователя - скачать обновленные файлы (файлы, которые имеют более свежую дату изменения)
3. Если данных файлов нет на машине пользователя - скачать все существующие файлы из директории FTP и залить в папку, указанную пользователем.

Вот как реализовал частично это я (проверка на существование нужных файлов и директорий):

```
private void labelAccept_MouseDown_1(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                RegistryKey key = Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey("SOFTWARE\\SAMP");
                key.SetValue(reg_pName, $"{textBoxPlayerName.Text}");

                // проверка на существующую директорию
                string currentDirectory = @"" + txtBoxPath.Text;
                if (Directory.Exists(currentDirectory))
                {
                    key.SetValue("gta_sa_exe", $"{txtBoxPath.Text}");                                   // path to game
                    MessageBox.Show("Путь к игре сохранен успешно!");

                }
                else if (!Directory.Exists(currentDirectory))
                    MessageBox.Show("Директория указана неверно, либо не существует!");
                else
                    MessageBox.Show("Файл gta_sa.exe не найден!");

                // сохранение состояний чек боксов
                // здесь
            }
```

Функция, которая устанавливает файлы с FTP, если нужные файлы не обнаружены (некорректно выводит размер файла):

```
 private void get_install()
        {
            string ftp_login = "hidden";
            string ftp_pass = "hidden";

            // ftp
            const string url = "ftp://hidden/Game.zip";
            // exception
            try
            {
                NetworkCredential _credentials = new NetworkCredential(ftp_login, ftp_pass);
                // проверить подключение *удачно или нет*
                // не знаю как, может сам найду, но буду благодарен за помощь


                // запрос на размер загружаемых файлов с FTP
                // Query size of the file to be downloaded
                WebRequest sizeRequest = WebRequest.Create(url);
                sizeRequest.Credentials = _credentials;
                sizeRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.GetFileSize;
                int size = (int)sizeRequest.GetResponse().ContentLength;
                MessageBox.Show(size.ToString());


// загрузка 
                WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url);
                request.Credentials = _credentials;
                request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile;

                Settings st = new Settings();

                using (Stream ftpStream = request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream())
                using (Stream fileStream = File.Create(@"" + st.txtBoxPath.Text))
                {
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[10240];
                    int read;

                    // попытка реализовать прогресс бар, который будет показывать прогресс загрузки
                    while ((read = ftpStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
                    {
                        fileStream.Write(buffer, 0, read);
                        int position = (int)fileStream.Position;
                        //ProgressBar1_Copy4.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() => progressBar1.Value = position));      // .Net ругает, возможно из-за WPF
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception) { }
```

Согласен, очень косячный код, впервые сталкиваюсь с таким огромным фронтом работы, тем не менее, средствами поисковых систем, навыков чтения документации, что-то удалось вывести.

И еще момент, нужно чтобы скачивались файлы в том случае, если их версия новее версии, которая лежит у пользователя на ПК. Я пытался сделать через File.Version, по-моему так, но в FTP не прокатывало, она все равно продолжала записывать все файлы на пользовательскую машину. А нужно конкретно те, которые новее или же, если некоторые файлы отсутствует  - докачать их.

Comment: Окей, у вас есть задача и вы её делаете. Это хорошо. Но в чем ваш вопрос?

Comment: Завис на реализации проверки версии файлов, нужно чтобы сверялись файлы, которые на ftp с теми, что на пк пользователя и обновлялись на новые. Также с прогресс баром проблема (пометил в коде) ругается .Net.

Comment: @tym32167 в конце, последний абзац, там явно подчеркнуто то, в чем имеется проблема)

Comment: 1) почему не используете clickonce? 2) вы можете на сервере подготовить файлик (например, xml или json) и в этом файлов в на сервере прописать всю нужную информацию по каждому файлу приложения - версии, хеши, даты и тд. После этого качать только этот файлик и считать, какие файлы надо обновить?

Comment: `Завис на реализации проверки версии файлов, нужно чтобы сверялись файлы` это все еще выглядит как ваша задача. То, что вы зависли, не говорит ничего о вашей проблеме. У вас ошибка какая то или что случилось?

Comment: Как еще вариант, почему бы просто не держать на сервере отдельные папки для отдельных версий и качать все приложение полностью на каждое обновление?

Comment: Почему FTP? Надеюсь, это приложение не для пользователей. Потому что FTP не везде будет работать даже в пассивном режиме. Задача решатеся либо с помощью системы контроля версий, либо с помощью апдейт-сервиса - сервера, который владеет информацией о файлах. По поводу почему не работает - отлаживайте, ставьте точку останова, смотрите значения переменных. Еще можно использовать HTTP и заголовки для контроля версий, браузерный кеш именно так и работает. Отправляешь `if-modified-since` и дату, и если ответ 304, значит не изменился, если 200 - качаем.

Comment: FTP нужен тогда, когда вам надо что-то залить на сервер с клиентской машины. Если скачать - лучше чем HTTP не найти. FTP может прокатить, если приложение для личного пользования, либо внутрикорпоративное, где контроль за сетью вам доступен. Для домашних или мобильных пользователей FTP противопоказан по техническим причинам.

Comment: @aepot спасибо, помог